# Overiding a Autowired object on class construction

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

I have a class that uses an autowired properties object. These properties have some configuration required in order for my communications to work properly. In my unit tests I wrote a scenario in which communication should fail, by overriding the properties object in the class constructor as follows:

```
public class TokenRetriever{

    @Autowired
    private TokenRepository repository;
    @Autowired
    private Properties properties;

    //custom constructor for me to override the properties
    public TokenRetriever(Properties properties){
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    private Token retrieveToken() {
        Token token = null;
        try {
            //communication to an endpoint using properties
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return token;
    }

    public Token getAccessToken() throws NullAccessToken {
        Token token;
        token = repository.findTop1ByExpiresAtGreaterThanOrderByExpiresAtDesc(LocalDateTime.now());
        if (token == null) token = this.retrieveToken();
        if (token == null) throw new NullAccessToken("Could not retrieve any tokens");
        return token;
    }
}
```

And this is my unit test:

```
@Test
    void ShouldNotRetrieveAToken() {
        //this is the property i'm changing in order to force a failure
        properties.setClientId("dummy");
        tokenRetriever = new TokenRetriever(properties);
        Exception exception = assertThrows(NullAccessToken.class,
                () ->
                        tokenRetriever.getAccessToken()
        );
        String expectedMessage = "Could not retrieve any tokens";
        String actualMessage = exception.getMessage();
        assertTrue(actualMessage.contains(expectedMessage));
    }
```

Which works just fine when I run the unit test. However, when I build the project this fails because the error is not thrown. I assume this is because the overriding is not working. I'm new to spring boot and junits, so this probably has to do with spring lifecycles. How can I accomplish the properties overide in order for my junit to pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructor injection Does injection only when the object create.
if you want create another object with different property object you must use Setter-based dependency injection.
there is setter-based injection documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-setter-injection

Comment: Alizera, I get the same error after I created a setter for that field.

Comment: Alizera, in the end it was another piece of code of mine that caused your solution to not work. The setter solution worked properly.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend setter injection. Setter injection should only be used for optional dependencies. https://www.amitph.com/spring-field-setter-constructor-injection/

Comment: Read also this from the Spring Team https://spring.io/blog/2007/07/11/setter-injection-versus-constructor-injection-and-the-use-of-required

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing constructor and field injection.

It's recommended to use constructor injection where possible. You also will not need an annotation.

```
private final TokenRepository repository;
private final Properties properties;

public TokenRetriever(TokenRepository repository, Properties properties){
    this.repository = repository;
    this.properties = properties;
}
```

Comment: By doing so I get a NPE on my other autowired fields. I didn't upload the whole code to focus on the problem at hand. The question is now editted.

Comment: Note the tokenRepository is null when I instanciate TokenRetriever using: TokenRetriever tokenRetriever = new TokenRetriever(properties);

Comment: I overlooked the other dependency. Simply use constructor injection for all dependencies. I've updated my anser